# How to remove UTF16 characters from string?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a string containing special characters, like:

Hello .

As far as I understand "" is an UTF16 character.

How can I remove this "" character and any other not UTF8 characters from string?

The problem is that .Net and JavaScript see it as two valid UTF8 characters:

```
int cs_len = "".Length; // == 2 - C#
var js_len = "".length  // == 2 - javascript
```

where

strIn[0] is 55356 UTF8 character == ☐

and

strIn[1] is 57152 UTF8 character == ☐

And also next code snippets returns the same result:

```
string strIn = "Hello ";
string res;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strIn);
res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
return res;//Hello
```

and

```
        string res = null;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var sw = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

            sw.Write(strIn);                
            sw.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                res = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return res;//Hello
```

I also need to support not only English but also Chinese and Japanese and any other languages, also any other UTF8 characters. How can I remove or replace any UTF16 characters in C# or JavaScript code, including  sign.

Thanks.

Comment: Umm, "UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible characters, or code points, defined by Unicode" - so how can a character be an "UTF16 character" but not an "UTF8 character"?? Your example "" is `3C D8 40 DF` in UTF-16 and `F0 9F 8D 80` in UTF-8.

Comment: The only difference is the amount of bytes they take when serialized, but one character is only one character on a string, in javascript and in C#.

Comment: @piet.t it can be two UTF8 characters as far as I see here, because UTF16 contains more than UTF8 characters.

Comment: I see your problem, it's not actually related to UTF8. That character is an UTF16 surrogate pair. Not actually sure how to get rid of them or why you would want that. Any system that properly support UTF should be able to render it if the font supports it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF

Comment: The question would be why would you care about the exact count of "apparent" characters?

Comment: I don't care about the exact count, I just want to replace them.


As far as I saw, the last character number in UTF8 is 100540:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm?start=100540.

So I wanted to verify each character if its number is less than 100541,
and if it is, its a valid UTF8 character, otherwise replace it.
But, when I check this special sign, javascript sees it as two separate characters, with number of each less than 100541 (55356 and 57152), and my replacement function does not replace them.

Comment: replacement function:
function cleanString(input) {

    var output = "";

    var num;

    for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {

        num = input.charCodeAt(i);

        console.log(input[i] + ': ' + num);

        if (num <= 100540 ) {

            output += input.charAt(i);

        }
    else
    {
        output += '*';
    }

    }

    return output;

}

Comment: @user6704497 "As far as I saw, the last character number in UTF8 is 100540" - No, it isn't. See e.g. here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2f825/index.htm *There is no difference in the range of encodable characters ebtween UTF-8 and UTF-16*!!!

Answer (score 1):

UTF-16 and UTF-8 "contain" the same number of "characters" (to be precise: of code points that may represent a character, thanks to David Haim), the only difference is how they are encoded to bytes.

In your example "" is `3C D8 40 DF` in UTF-16 and `F0 9F 8D 80` in UTF-8.

From your problem-description and your pasted string I suspect that your sourcecode is encoded in UTF-8 but your compiler/interpreter is reading it as UTF-16. So it will interpret the one-character UTF-sequence `F0 9F 8D 80` as two separate UTF-16-characters `F0 9f` and `8D 80` - the first is an invalid unicode-character and the second is the "Han Character".

As for how to solve the issue:

In your example you should look at the editor you use for creating your sources what encoding it uses to save the files plus you should check whether you can specify that encoding as a compiler-option.

You should also be aware that things will look quite different once you don't use hardcoded string-literals but read your input from a file or over the network - you will have to handle encoding-issues already when reading your input.

Comment: they container the same number of *code points*, not the same number fo characters

Comment: @DavidHaim thanks for the correction - I tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my question, it does not covers all the utf-16 characters, but removes many of them:

```
var title = 
title.replace(/([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF])/g, '*');
```

Here, I replace all special characters with a "star" `*`. You can also put an empty string `''` to remove them.

The meaning of `/g` at the end of the string, is to remove all the occurrences of these special characters, because without it string.replace(...) probably will remove only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
string teste = @"F:\Thiago\Programação\Projetos\OnlineAppfdsdf^~²$\XML\nfexml";
        string strConteudo = Regex.Replace(teste, "[^0-9a-zA-Z\\.\\,\\/\\x20\\/\\x1F\\-\\r\\n]+", string.Empty);
       
        WriteLine($"Teste: {teste}" +
            $"\nTeste2: {strConteudo}");
```